# Pandas: Add rows to a dataframe using one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like following:

```
col1   col2 
1      [1,2,3]
2      [1,2]
3      [1]
```

I want to exapnd the dataframe on the basis of `col2` such that the values of other columns gets copied in the new rows as following.

```
col1    col2
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        2
3        1
```

I've scoured prior questions for something to get me started, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked before... with a little modification you can use anything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings.

Comment: If you're using my solution, use `np.concatenate(df.col2.tolist())` to unwrap the elements.