# Pandas entry of type list?

Tags: python, pandas

Can a column in pandas be of type np.array? or python list etc?
I'm trying to have

```
    a         array_col
0   100       [1,2,8,0]
1   5         [1,3 4,8]      
2   3         [1,2 4,8]
```

All columns would be of the same length if it's relevant.
The functionality I'm after is to initialize all array_col to [0,0,...0], and then for each row to manipulate the array depending on the row, and the previous array(`e.g on row n, multiply all the array by n, and make array_col[n] = 0`)
The alternative is to make a new column for each index (i.e 30 new columns in my case, and make the manipulation much slower).
Ideas?
Edit:
I would like something like that:

```
df

    a         
0   100       
1   5               
2   3 

df['hist'] = [1,2,3]


df

    a         array_col
0   100       [1,2,3]
1   5         [1,2,3]      
2   3         [1,2,3]
```

But both

```
df['hist'] = [1,2,3]
```

and

```
df['hist'] = np.zeros(3)
```

gives the error

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: May check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings/48197300#48197300

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [100, 5, 3], 'array_col': [ [1,2,8,0], [1,3,4,8], [1,2,4,8] ] })`

Comment: RafaelC this does work, how can I make it after the df is created?

Comment: `(i.e 30 new columns in my case, and make the manipulation much slower).` Are you certain? I'd think even 30 columns of type `int` are easier / faster to manipulate than a series of lists. Don't use `list` within a Pandas series unless you have **proven** to yourself it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example could be solved like this:

```
df['hist'] = [[1, 2, 3] for _ in range(df.size)]
df
#     a       hist
#0  100  [1, 2, 3]
#1    5  [1, 2, 3]
#2    3  [1, 2, 3]
```

Or:

```
df['hist'] = [np.zeros(3) for _ in range(df.size)]
df
#     a             hist
#0  100  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
#1    5  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
#2    3  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

And to get desired output - assign nested list:

```
df['hist'] = [[1,2,8,0],[1,3,4,8],[1,2,4,8]]
df
#     a          hist
#0  100  [1, 2, 8, 0]
#1    5  [1, 3, 4, 8]
#2    3  [1, 2, 4, 8]
```