# Convert cells in dataframe with multiple values to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this:

```
Name    test1     test2      Count
Emp1    X,Y        A           1
Emp2    X          A,B,C       2
Emp3    Z          C           3
```

I'm using the code below to split **test1** cells with multiple values to individual rows. However, I am not sure how to split **Test2** column.

```
df2 = df.test1.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
df2.index = df.set_index(['Name', 'count']).index
df2.stack().reset_index(['Name', 'count'])
df2
```

And the output  is:

```
Name    test1   Count
Emp1    X        1
Emp1    Y        1
Emp2    X        2
Emp2    X        2
Emp2    X        2
Emp2    Z        3
```

I'm trying to split **test1** and **test2** so that I can achieve this output:

```
Name    test1    test2  Count
Emp1    X          A      1
Emp1    Y          A      1
Emp2    X          A      2
Emp2    X          B      2
Emp2    X          C      2
Emp2    Z          C      3
```

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just fix your code , since I do not recommend the method you unnesting the dataframe , you can check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings) here, there are multiple nice way.

```
df2 = df.test1.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
df2.index = df.set_index(['Name', 'Count']).index
df2=df2.stack().reset_index(['Name', 'Count'])
df3 = df.test2.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
df3.index = df.set_index(['Name', 'Count']).index
df3=df3.stack().reset_index(['Name', 'Count'])
```

## Just do `merge` here

```
df2.merge(df3,on=['Name', 'Count'],how='outer')
Out[132]: 
   Name  Count 0_x 0_y
0  Emp1      1   X   A
1  Emp1      1   Y   A
2  Emp2      2   X   A
3  Emp2      2   X   B
4  Emp2      2   X   C
5  Emp3      3   Z   C
```

Comment: @Mahesh I have tried to make my solution as generalized as possible. Take a look later and see if helps ;)

Comment: @RafaelC I tried the expand_all function you suggested, I observe that it is expanding the columns which are already expanded . . This is leading to duplication of values

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is that straightforward to adapt [this answer highlighted by @wen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings) to this question, so I'll propose a solution.

You might create a function that takes a `df`, a column to be expanded and a separator for that column, and chain calls as many times as needed.

```
def expand(df, col, sep=','):
    r = df[col].str.split(sep)
    d = {c: df[c].values.repeat(r.str.len(), axis=0) for c in df.columns}
    d[col] = [i for sub in r for i in sub]
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

expand(expand(df, 'test1'), 'test2')

    Name    test1   test2   Count
0   Emp1    X       A       1
1   Emp1    Y       A       1
2   Emp2    X       A       2
3   Emp2    X       B       2
4   Emp2    X       C       2
5   Emp3    Z       C       3
```

Suppose you have a

```
df['test3'] = ['X1|X2|X3', 'X4', 'X5']
```

such that

```
>>> print(df)

    Name    test1   test2   Count   test3
0   Emp1    X,Y     A       1       X1|X2|X3
1   Emp2    X       A,B,C   2       X4
2   Emp3    Z       C       3       X5
```

Then,

```
>>> expand(df,'test3', '|')

    Name    test1   test2   Count   test3
0   Emp1    X,Y     A       1       X1
1   Emp1    X,Y     A       1       X2
2   Emp1    X,Y     A       1       X3
3   Emp2    X       A,B,C   2       X4
4   Emp3    Z       C       3       X5
```

If you think columns size may increase *substantially*, you can define a function `expand_all` to avoid having something like `expand(expand(expand(expand(........))))))`. For example:

```
def expand_all(df, cols, seps):
    ret = df
    for c,s in zip(cols,seps): ret = expand(ret,c,s)
    return ret

>>> expand_all(df, ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], [',', ',', '|'])

    Name    test1   test2   Count   test3
0   Emp1    X       A       1       X1
1   Emp1    X       A       1       X2
2   Emp1    X       A       1       X3
3   Emp1    Y       A       1       X1
4   Emp1    Y       A       1       X2
5   Emp1    Y       A       1       X3
6   Emp2    X       A       2       X4
7   Emp2    X       B       2       X4
8   Emp2    X       C       2       X4
9   Emp3    Z       C       3       X5
```

Or however suitable ;)

---

Detail:

```
>>> expand(df, 'test1')

    Name    test1   test2   Count
0   Emp1    X       A       1
1   Emp1    Y       A       1
2   Emp2    X       A,B,C   2
3   Emp3    Z       C       3

>>> expand(df, 'test2')

    Name    test1   test2   Count
0   Emp1    X,Y     A       1
1   Emp2    X       A       2
2   Emp2    X       B       2
3   Emp2    X       C       2
4   Emp3    Z       C       3

>>> expand(expand(df, 'test2'), 'test1') 

    Name    test1   test2   Count
0   Emp1    X       A       1
1   Emp1    Y       A       1
2   Emp2    X       A       2
3   Emp2    X       B       2
4   Emp2    X       C       2
5   Emp3    Z       C       3


>>> expand(expand(df, 'test2'), 'test1').eq(expand(expand(df, 'test1'), 'test2')).all()

Name     True
test1    True
test2    True
Count    True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(n, a, b, c)
     for n, A, B, c in zip(*map(df.get, df))
     for a in A.split(',') for b in B.split(',')],
    columns=df.columns
)

   Name test1 test2  Count
0  Emp1     X     A      1
1  Emp1     Y     A      1
2  Emp2     X     A      2
3  Emp2     X     B      2
4  Emp2     X     C      2
5  Emp3     Z     C      3
```