# Split sentences in pandas into sentence number and words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Text            start    end    entity     value
I love apple      7       11    fruit      apple
I ate potato      6       11    vegetable  potato
```

I have tried to use a for loop
It's running slow and I don't think this is what we should do with pandas.

I want to create another pandas dataframe base on this like:

```
Sentence#         Word        Tag
  1                I         Object 
  1               love       Object
  1               apple      fruit
  2                I         Object
  2               ate        Object
  2               potato     vegetable
```

Split the text column into words and sentence numbers. Other than the entity word, the other words will be tagged as Object.

Comment: This is going to be much much harder if "value" has phrases or sentences (i.e., more than a single word).

Comment: @coldspeed I do encounter this problem now that 'value' has phrases and sentences, do you happen to know the solution of this much harder problem?

Comment: It is a much more involved solution... I recommend opening a new question. If you do not have an answer in 2 days, let me know and I'll instate a bounty on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `split`, `stack` and `map`:

```
u = df.Text.str.split(expand=True).stack()

pd.DataFrame({
    'Sentence': u.index.get_level_values(0) + 1, 
    'Word': u.values, 
    'Entity': u.map(dict(zip(df.value, df.entity))).fillna('Object').values
})

   Sentence    Word     Entity
0         1       I     Object
1         1    love     Object
2         1   apple      fruit
3         2       I     Object
4         2     ate     Object
5         2  potato  vegetable
```

Side note: If running v0.24 or later, [please use `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/4909087).

Comment: Love this answer. Clean piece of code. Sidenote: pandas doc recommends `.to_numpy()` over `.values`

Comment: @Erfan [I know ;D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/4909087) Only thing is, if OP is on an older version (very likely), `to_numpy` will just throw an attribute error. But I will make a note of that in the answer.

Comment: I see makes sense. Shoudlve been more clear. I meant a sidenote as well.

Comment: Btw thanks for linking that thread, great piece of information. Couldnt find this in the docs. Was wondering what the reason for deprecation of `.values` was.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) here after `str.split`

```
df.Text=df.Text.str.split(' ')
yourdf=unnesting(df,['Text'])
yourdf.loc[yourdf.Text.values!=yourdf.value.values,'entity']='object'
yourdf
     Text  start  end     entity   value
0       I      7   11     object   apple
0    love      7   11     object   apple
0   apple      7   11      fruit   apple
1       I      6   11     object  potato
1     ate      6   11     object  potato
1  potato      6   11  vegetable  potato
```

Comment: Wow, never saw that thread, awesome. Have faved in my bookmarks ;}

Answer (score 2):

Using the `expand` function [I posted in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351102/convert-cells-in-dataframe-with-multiple-values-to-multiple-rows/52351226), you can

```
df = expand(df, 'Text', sep=' ')
```

Then simple

```
df['Tag'] = np.where(df.Text.ne(df.value), ['Object'], df.entity)


>>> df[['Text', 'Tag']]

    Text    Tag
0   I       Object
1   love    Object
2   apple   fruit
3   I       Object
4   ate     Object
5   potato  vegetable
```

---

```
def expand(df, col, sep=','):
    r = df[col].str.split(sep)
    d = {c: df[c].values.repeat(r.str.len(), axis=0) for c in df.columns}
    d[col] = [i for sub in r for i in sub]
    return pd.DataFrame(d)
```