# Pandas split sentence and label phrases to perform BIO tagging

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have labeled data like this:

```
    Data = {'text': ['when can I decrease the contribution to my health savings?', 'I love my guinea pig', 'I love my dog'],
        'start':[43, 10, 10],
        'end':[57,19, 12],
        'entity':['hsa', 'pet', 'pet'],
        'value':['health savings', 'guinea pig', 'dog']
       } 
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data)

       text               start  end         entity     value
0   .. health savings      43    57          hsa      health savings
1   I love my guinea pig   10    19          pet      guinea pig
2   I love my dog          10    12          pet         dog
```

Want to split sentences into words and tag each word. If the word is associated with an entity, tag it with that entity.

I have tried the way in this question:
[Split sentences in pandas into sentence number and words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444976/split-sentences-in-pandas-into-sentence-number-and-words?noredirect=1#comment97936538_55444976)

But that method only works when the value is a single word like 'dog' but won't work if the value is a phrase like 'guinea pig'

Want to perform BIO tagging. B stands for beginning of a phrase. I stands for inside of a phrase. O stands for outside.

Thus the desired output will be:

```
    Sentence #  Word         Entity
0   Sentence: 0 when            O
1   Sentence: 0 can             O
2   Sentence: 0 I               O
3   Sentence: 0 decrease        O
4   Sentence: 0 the             O
5   Sentence: 0 contribution    O
6   Sentence: 0 to              O
7   Sentence: 0 my              O
8   Sentence: 0 health          B-hsa
9   Sentence: 0 savings?        I-hsa
10  Sentence: 1 I               O
11  Sentence: 1 love            O
12  Sentence: 1 my              O
13  Sentence: 1 guinea          B-pet
14  Sentence: 1 pig             I-pet
15  Sentence: 2 I               O
16  Sentence: 2 love            O
17  Sentence: 2 my              O
18  Sentence: 2 dog             B-pet
```

Comment: Does the answer solved your problem,if yes please accept for future users!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['value','entity'], append=True)
         .text.str.split(expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='Word')
         .rename(columns={'level_0':'Sentence'}))

df1['Sentence'] = 'Sentence: ' + df1['Sentence'].astype(str)
w = df1['Word'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
splitted = df1.pop('value').str.split()
e = df1.pop('entity')

m1 = splitted.str[0].eq(w)
m2 = [b in a for a, b in zip(splitted, w)]

df1['Entity'] = np.select([m1, m2 & ~m1], ['B-' + e, 'I-' + e],  default='O')
```

---

```
print (df1)

       Sentence          Word Entity
0   Sentence: 0          when      O
1   Sentence: 0           can      O
2   Sentence: 0             I      O
3   Sentence: 0      decrease      O
4   Sentence: 0           the      O
5   Sentence: 0  contribution      O
6   Sentence: 0            to      O
7   Sentence: 0            my      O
8   Sentence: 0        health  B-hsa
9   Sentence: 0      savings?  I-hsa
10  Sentence: 1             I      O
11  Sentence: 1          love      O
12  Sentence: 1            my      O
13  Sentence: 1        guinea  B-pet
14  Sentence: 1           pig  I-pet
15  Sentence: 2             I      O
16  Sentence: 2          love      O
17  Sentence: 2            my      O
18  Sentence: 2           dog  B-pet
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create new `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
2. some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename`
3. Prepend string to `Sentence`column
4. Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for remove punctuation
5. Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and `split` for lists
6. Create mask `m1` by compare first value of splited lists
7. Create mask for compare all values of lists
8. Create new column by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Split your column value based on space by below code:**

```
s = df['value'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) # to line up with df's index
s.name = 'value' # needs a name to join
del df['value']
df1 = df.join(s)
df1 =df1.reset_index()
```

The above step will break your phrases to single words

**Step 2**: `df1` will have values where a new value column and now all you need to do is change your entity column w.r.t to new `value` column

```
prev_id = 'x'
for idx,ser in df1.iterrows():
    if ser.text == prev_id:
        df1.loc[idx,'entity'] = 'I-HSA'
    else:
        df1.loc[idx,'entity'] = 'B-HSA'
    prev_id = ser.text
```

Above code changes the `entity` field with logic that similar consecutive text will value will change the value as asked.

**Step 3**: After this your dataframe is similar to the link you posted, simply apply the same solution.

The above answer is taking care of your phrase problem as mentioned in your problem