# pandas calculate counts by months

Tags: python, pandas

how to count items in each month with fill?

```
data = [
        {"event_date": "2018-08-10", "tags": ["tv", "radio"]},
        {"event_date": "2018-08-11", "tags": ["tv", "radio"]},
        {"event_date": "2018-09-10", "tags": ["tv"]},
        {"event_date": "2018-11-10", "tags": ["tv", "wifi"]}
    ] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby([(df['event_date']).dt.month, df['tags']]).count()
```

what I expect:

```
month tv radio wifi
8 2 2 0
9 1 0 0
10 0 0 0
11 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar method to [@Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635874/3483203), but creating a new DataFrame to avoid the `apply`:

```
s = (pd.DataFrame(df.tags.values.tolist(),
        index=df.event_date.dt.month).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True))
```

Now using `pd.get_dummies`:

```
(pd.get_dummies(s).sum(level=0)
    .reindex(np.arange(s.index.min(),s.index.max()+1), fill_value=0))
```

```
            radio  tv  wifi
event_date
8               2   2     0
9               0   1     0
10              0   0     0
11              0   1     1
```

Comment: I feel like I am too lazy ( writing done repeat) :-) , BTW Nice one

Comment: Mine could be much cleaner, I always forget you can sum across levels :P I'm also stealing your `fill_value`

Comment: Any idea how the performance of something like `df.tags.str.join('*').str.get_dummies(sep='*')` to get the dummies holds up? I'm always so clueless about the `.str` methods.

Comment: Hmm, I'd have to try it out.  I'd imagine it could be faster than expanding the lists to a new series, but I don't think it would beat creating the new DataFrame.  String operations are unfortunately slow in pandas.

Comment: Yeah it gets pretty slow actually, your method is pretty fast :D

Answer (score 5):

So this is [unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings/48197300#48197300) ,`get_dummies` and `reindex` mixed question

```
df.event_date=pd.to_datetime(df.event_date).dt.month

l=list(range(df.event_date.min(),df.event_date.max()+1))
df.set_index('event_date').tags.apply(pd.Series).stack().\
  str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).\
   reindex(l,fill_value=0)
Out[834]: 
            radio  tv  wifi
event_date                 
8               2   2     0
9               0   1     0
10              0   0     0
11              0   1     1
```