# How to construct a list comprehension with nested for loops and conditionals for pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, list-comprehension

I'm having difficulty getting the following complex list comprehension to work as expected. It's a double nested for loop with conditionals.

Let me first explain what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'stringA':['ABCDBAABDCBD','BBXB'], 'stringB':['ABDCXXXBDDDD', 'AAAB'], 'num':[42, 13]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
        stringA       stringB  num
0  ABCDBAABDCBD  ABDCXXXBDDDD   42
1          BBXB          AAAB   13
```

This DataFrame has two columns `stringA` and `stringB` with strings containing characters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `X`. By definition, these two strings have the same length.

Based on these two columns, I create dictionaries such that `stringA` begins at index 0, and `stringB` begins at the index starting at `num`.

Here's the function I use:

```
def create_translation(x):
    x['translated_dictionary'] = {i: i +x['num'] for i, e in enumerate(x['stringA'])}
    return x

df2 = df.apply(create_translation, axis=1).groupby('stringA')['translated_dictionary']


df2.head()
0    {0: 42, 1: 43, 2: 44, 3: 45, 4: 46, 5: 47, 6: ...
1                         {0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15, 3: 16}
Name: translated_dictionary, dtype: object

print(df2.head()[0])
{0: 42, 1: 43, 2: 44, 3: 45, 4: 46, 5: 47, 6: 48, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 51, 10: 52, 11: 53}

print(df2.head()[1])
{0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15, 3: 16}
```

That's correct.

However, there are 'X' characters in these strings. That requires a special rule: If `X` is in `stringA`, don't create a key-value pair in the dictionary. If `X` is in `stringB`, then the value should not be `i + x['num']` but `-500`.

I tried the following list comprehension:

```
def try1(x):
    for count, element in enumerate(x['stringB']):
        x['translated_dictionary'] = {i: -500 if element == 'X' else  i + x['num'] for i, e in enumerate(x['stringA']) if e != 'X'}
    return x
```

That gives the wrong answer.

```
df3 = df.apply(try1, axis=1).groupby('stringA')['translated_dictionary']

print(df3.head()[0]) ## this is wrong!
{0: 42, 1: 43, 2: 44, 3: 45, 4: 46, 5: 47, 6: 48, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 51, 10: 52, 11: 53}

print(df3.head()[1])   ## this is correct! There is no key for 2:15!
{0: 13, 1: 14, 3: 16}
```

There are no -500 values!

The correct answer is:

```
print(df3.head()[0])
{0: 42, 1: 43, 2: 44, 3: 45, 4:-500, 5:-500, 6:-500, 7: 49, 8: 50, 9: 51, 10: 52, 11: 53}

print(df3.head()[1])
{0: 13, 1: 14, 3: 16}
```

Comment: Why does your last example have 13, 14, 16 instead of 13, 14, 15?

Comment: @JohnZwinck That's based on the first rule. "If X is in stringA, don't create a key-value pair in the dictionary." In this case, `BBXB` has an X at 2:15. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way, without any comprehensions (because they aren't helping clarify the code):

```
def create_translation(x):
    out = {}
    num = x['num']
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(x['stringA'], x['stringB'])):
        if a == 'X':
            pass
        elif b == 'X':
            out[i] = -500
        else:
            out[i] = num
        num += 1
    x['translated_dictionary'] = out
    return x
```

Comment: This works! I hadn't thought about keeping tracking of `num` as a local variable and iterating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not flatten your df , you can check with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/explode-stack-a-series-of-strings/48197300#48197300) and recreate the `dict`

```
n=df.stringA.str.len()
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'num':df.num.repeat(n),'stringA':sum(list(map(list,df.stringA)),[]),'stringB':sum(list(map(list,df.stringB)),[])})


newdf=newdf.loc[newdf.stringA!='X'].copy()# remove stringA value X
newdf['value']=newdf.groupby('num').cumcount()+newdf.num # using groupby create the cumcount 
newdf.loc[newdf.stringB=='X','value']=-500# assign -500 when stringB is X
[dict(zip(x.groupby('num').cumcount(),x['value']))for _,x in newdf.groupby('num')] # create the dict for different num by group
Out[390]: 
[{0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15},
 {0: 42,
  1: 43,
  2: 44,
  3: 45,
  4: -500,
  5: -500,
  6: -500,
  7: 49,
  8: 50,
  9: 51,
  10: 52,
  11: 53}]
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you're doing above?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang check it , updated . Also for the flatten one , I did not explain here, you can check the linked post .