# How to expand/separate into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, row

```
    column1     column2
    MGI:97874   MP 0008796;MP 0009395;MP 0009937;MP 0011098;MP 0011703
    MGI:96522   MP 0001614;MP 0000364;MP 0006093
    MGI:83838   MP 4209998;MP 2838838;MP 8283904;MP 9384784
```

My question is how to expand the rows of the same value (in column 1) into multiple lines, so the output will be like that:

```
    MGI:97874   MP 0008796
    MGI:97874   MP 0009395
    MGI:97874   MP 0009937
    MGI:97874   MP 0011098
    MGI:97874   MP 0011703
    MGI:96522   MP 0001614
    MGI:96522   MP 0000364
    MGI:96522   MP 0006093
    MGI:83838   MP 4209998
    MGI:83838   MP 2838838
    MGI:83838   MP 8283904
    MGI:83838   MP 9384784
```

Someone shared this with me: [Unnest (explode) a Pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/unnest-explode-a-pandas-series)

but it's a bit different and it's split mine into letters which I don't want!

Comment: I didn't understand the way that much! @WeNYoBen

Comment: Change to df.column2.str.split(';')

Comment: Where exactly!, I don't see this line even with another column @WeNYoBen