# How to a row in pandas based on column condition?

Tags: pandas

[image]I have a pandas data frame and I would like to duplicate those rows which meet some column condition (i.e. having multiple elements in CourseID column)

I tried iterating over the data frame to identify the rows which should be duplicated but i don't know how to duplicate them,

[image: Here is the link to the expected output]

Comment: Please post the data directly into your question rather than using images or external links

Comment: There are multiple questions on this topic, also look at df.explode: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unnest (explode) a Pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197234/unnest-explode-a-pandas-series)

Answer (score 0):

Using *Pandas* version *0.25* it is quite easy:

The first step is to split *df.CourseID* (converting each element to a list)
and then to explode it (break each list into multiple rows,
repeating other columns in each row):

```
course = df.CourseID.str.split(',').explode()
```

The result is:

```
0    456
1    456
1    799
2    789
Name: CourseID, dtype: object
```

Then, all to do is to join *df* with *course*, but in order to avoid
repeating column names, you have to drop original *CourseID* column before.
Fortunately, in can be expressed in a single instruction:

```
df.drop(columns=['CourseID']).join(course)
```

If you have some older version of *Pandas* this is a good reason to
upgrade it.